# Modify tooltip on show more text in react-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar) to show events in only Month view. Now when the number of events grow in a single day and the '+{total} more' text starts to appear, I want to show a tooltip with all events of that day in the calendar.

I am only using a Month view and more text appears like:

[image]

Now I want to show all these event information in a tooltip when user hovers over, I tried and disabled the default behaviour of this text as it acts as a link:

```
<Calendar
                localizer={localizer}
                showAllEvents={false}
                defaultView={Views.MONTH}
                events={myEvents}
                style={calendarHeight}
                eventPropGetter={myStyle}
                onNavigate={handleCalendarNavigate}
                messages={{
                    showMore: total => (
                      <Box style={{cursor: 'auto'}}
                           onMouseOver={e => {
                               console.log(`onMouseOver`);
                           }}
                           onClick={e => {
                               e.stopPropagation();
                               e.preventDefault();
                           }}>{`+${total} more`}
                      </Box>
                    )
                }}
                views={['month']}/>
```

I am getting a callback in the `onMouseOver` function but do I identify which date is being hovered over to show that information?

Answer (score 0):

The '+X more` button follows the following chain of logic.

- If `popup` is 'true' (it's defaulted to 'false') then it shows the
  popup.
- If `doShowMoreDrillDown` (undocumented prop) is 'true' then it
  drills down to the next view. You can provide your own
  `getDrilldownView` to override the default drilldown.
- If `onShowMore` is defined, it will run (in any event)

The `messages.showMore` prop was recently updated to provide some additional information

```js
/**
 * params {total} count of remaining events 
 * params {remainingEvents} remaining events 
 * params {events} all events in day
 */
showMore: (total, remainingEvents, events) => `+${total} más`,
```

How you change that is up to you, but you must realize that this is still in a button with a preset `onClick` handler that runs the above logic.